# debug Apk not running on android 12 and 13

Tags: javascript, react-native, build.gradle

on installation on Android 12 and 13, I get this error every time :
[permission is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64IxO.png)

1. My build doesn't reflect the changes made by me on apk, so i have used this command:
   react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
2. On using the above command reflects the changes in apk but the apk throws errors on android 12 and 13 devices saying permission is null.
3. Other versions work perfectly fine.
4. Without using the react-native bundle command apk runs successfully on every version but changes are not reflected.